# How to stop/start services of ambari cluster using AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, ambari

I wan't to pass the web services to AWS Lambda so that using those web services I can stop/start the services of ambari cluster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda can be easily integrated with almost all webservices including EC2 through programmatic api calls using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)

You just need to create a boto3 client of the aws service in lambda function and you can use them the way you want (for e.g start/stop) .

AWS Lambda also provides you to schedule its invocation.

As you have mentioned in the comment , you need to stop them using an api.

Here is the basic code snippet that works -

# you need to [create a zip](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) that includes requests lib and upload it in lambda function

```
import requests
# name of lambda_function that needs to invoke
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = ''
    json_body = {}
    try:
        api_response = requests.put(url=url, json=json_body)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

If you have these servers running in aws then you can create a boto3 client and use

```
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session
aws_access_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
aws_secret_key = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'
region = 'xx-yyyyyy'
def lambda_handler(event, context): 
     try:
         sess = Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
                   aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key)
        ec2_conn = sess.client(service_name='ec2', region_name=region)
         response = client.start_instances(
                          InstanceIds=[
                              'i-xxxxxx','i-yyyyyy','i-zzzzzz',
                          ])
    except ClientError as e:
         print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

P.S: this is a basic snippet and can vary according to your use case

Comment: curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -i -H 'X-Requested-By: ambari' -X PUT -d '{"RequestInfo": {"context" :"Stop HDFS via REST"}, "Body": {"ServiceInfo": {"state": "INSTALLED"}}}' http://$HOST/api/v1/clusters/CLUSTER_NAME/services/HDFS                                   

Where to add this command ?

Comment: yes, want to schedule this command. So that on weekends, I'll firstly stop all services of  ambari server and then I'll stop the EC2 instances of my hadoop cluster.